# NSLocalizedString always fall back to english

Tags: iphone, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have a project with english and french translation. Everything used to work perfectly fine.
Now for some reason the language always fallback to english.

I tried to delete the English.lproj and French.lproj folders, regenerate them with genstrings : still same issue

I also tried to delete the app from the device, clean the target and deploy again, no results.

The language of the device didn't change since it has always been set to french.

P.S: My problem is very similar to this one, except that my project used to work fine :

[iPhone: NSLocalizedString reading from English .strings file even when another lang is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971513/iphone-nslocalizedstring-reading-from-english-strings-file-even-when-another-la)

Does anybody have any idea of what i could do ?

Thanks for your help,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

There are several details that you need to follow, including where in the project you drag the localized files.

Have a look at this tutorial for a step-by-step explanation:
http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

Comment: As i said it used to work for this very project. To be sure I have deleted the translation file and followed the steps described, no results.