# Ios Localization not working

Tags: ios, localization, nslocalizedstring

I have XCode Version 4.3.3 running and iOS 5.1.
i can do what i want. i can't get localization running. i added different languages through project files. I adjusted the InfoPlist.strings in every Language like this:

```
"key" = "value";
```

I have everywhere:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"key", nil);
```

No key is the same like its value. I have checked the which language is chosen:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

#### But the app constantly just shows the keys and no value when i run the App.

#### I ran out of ideas

I tried deleting and cleaning everything as described here:
[Localization not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061334/localization-not-working)

I tried copying the files described here:
[NSLocalizedString Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297051/nslocalizedstring-problem)

And all the files are in their language folder:
[iPhone: NSLocalizedString reading from English .strings file even when another lang is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971513/iphone-nslocalizedstring-reading-from-english-strings-file-even-when-another-l)

Does anybody have an idea what else i can do?!? i don't know what i am doing wrong?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a Localizable.strings file? That's the default file that

```
NSLocalizedString(@"key", nil);
```

looks for.

Comment: Wow, so simple?!? i changed the name of the automatic generated InfoPlist.strings to Localizable.strings and see it worked. Thank you very much. I thought Xcode is smart enough to name it right

Answer (score 0):

When using Xcode 5.1.1 and the 7.1 Simulator, the localisation is not reliable. 
Testing on real hardware does work.